# Chaining Multiple JSON Request Using Decodable - Swift 5

Tags: ios, json, swift, iphone

My "`url`" object has a link that captures what the user types into a search bar to complete the link then begin the JSON process. The first link responds with another link after the JSON has finished parsing. In my `if let validLink = result.link` you see I store the link information into an Array. Now I'm not sure if I should begin another JSON response in my `if let validLink = result` or if I should create a new function like I'm attempting to do in the code below and basically copied and pasted the same JSON information below to reparse it. The second link is getting a parse error. What is the most efficient and right way to do this? I'm really stuck here.

I've tried to create another function that uses the information from the first JSON parse to reparse again using the new link.

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

    if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text, !searchText.isEmpty {
        let url = URL(string: "http://djp-dev/api/item?q=\(String(describing: searchText))&dev=1")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
                guard let data = data,
                    error == nil else {
                        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
                        return }

                do {
                    let jsonResult = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
                    let resultsArray = jsonResult.results

                    for result in resultsArray {
                        if let validLink = result.link {
                            print(validLink)
                            self.collectLink.append(validLink)
                            self.mainParse()
                        }
                    }

                } catch {
                    print("Parse Error")
            }
        }
         task.resume()
    }
}

func mainParse() {
   let url = URL(string: "http://djp-dev\(collectLink[0])?dev=1")
    print(url!)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data,
            error == nil else {
                //print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
                return }

            do {
                let jsonResult = try JSONDecoder().decode(JSONResponse.self, from: data)
                let mainArray = jsonResult.locations

                for main in mainArray {
                   print("""
                        Manufacture = \(main.rid)
                        Description = \(main.description)
                        """)
                        /*if let validLink = result.description! {
                        }*/
                    }

                } catch {
                    print("Parse Error")
            }
        }
            task.resume()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

I basically ask `http://djp-dev/api/item?q=\(String(describing: searchText))&dev=1` for a link in the response it sends me back. I want the use the link it sends me to start another JSON request. I'm not sure if I should keep it all into one request or create a whole new function with a whole new JSON request. `if let validLink = result.link { }` is when I receive the second link information.

Comment: to make it reusable you could make a separte function to make the request pasing the url string or the url as parameter, but there is no problem doing another request inside the request, you have to check for retain cycles and bugs

Comment: Take a look at [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit), [Promises](https://github.com/google/promises), [then](https://github.com/freshOS/then), [BrightFutures](https://github.com/Thomvis/BrightFutures), [Hydra](https://github.com/malcommac/Hydra), etc. to chain requests after request easily, using the concept of "promises" (or "futures")!

Comment: @kjoe You got an example in mind? I tried to do it in the request but it seemed like the second request was messing up the first request.

Comment: @JayLee I've never really been into adding extra frameworks into my code. I would need all four or just PromiseKit should work fine right? How would you do it with promise kit?

Comment: @Dewan You can pick one that suits your needs, after taking a look at the docs. PromiseKit is mature and used in many projects, and Promises is from Google. If this question is the only nested-API calls in your project, I wouldn't add a dependency to solve this problem. However, if this pattern is common in your API calls, use one of those libraries to make your life easier!

Comment: I'll most likely only be making two JSON request only. First to the "url" link stated above which returns a response known as "link" which I append to an Array then reuse that link information to do another JSON request. After that I'll have all the information I need I'm sure.So I'm not sure if I'll need PromiseKit but maybe good to just use it in general. How would you do a chain request if I didn't end up using that anyways?

Comment: Does anyone have any idea how to do this without the frameworks? Some type of example I can start with?

Comment: You don't need a third-party framework. The workflow seems to be correct. But rather than meaningless `"Parse Error"` print the `error` instance to see what kind of error you get (`print(error)`). And it would help to see the JSON and the corresponding structs of the second request. And basically reload the tableview **inside** the completion handler.

Comment: @vadian So I'm doing everything right? When I see another request inside the request it seems insufficient to me but if you says it's correct I'll go along with it. Maybe it's a server side thing and my code is perfectly fine. I just can't seem to make it work. It must be something wrong with my Decodable structs

Comment: If you have two requests which rely on each other your way is correct. Debug your code, print the `error` instances, set breakpoints.

Comment: @vadian See verified answer. Thanks for helping me figure it out! I'm still a bit new to Decodable so I missed out on pretty much the obvious. I appreciate everything man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've figured it out. I was using Decodable without CodingKeys. Thanks to Vadian for pointing me in the right direction. Here's my example:

```
struct Response : Decodable {
    let results: [Results]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case results = "photos"
    }
}

struct Results : Decodable {
    let url : String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case url = "url"
    }
}
```

Comment: In the second struct you can omit the CodingKeys and if you name the array `photos` you can omit the CodingKeys in the first struct, too.

Comment: Finally had time to take a look, and I'm glad to see that you figured it out!

Comment: @JayLee Yes sir, I still do appreciate you for actually taking the time to take a look at this question for me. I haven't programmed in years and was a bit rusty but actually catching on now. Thanks man

Comment: @vadian What you mean? I could make the code cleaner is what you mean?

Comment: @Dewan Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

What @vadian is saying is, `Codable` autmagically uses variable names as a coding key. So you can simply add `Decodable` like:

```swift
struct Response: Decodable {
  let results: [Results]
  private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case results = "photos"
  }
}

struct Results: Decodable {
  let url: String?
}
```

and if you change the name of `results` to `photos`, you can do

```swift
struct Response: Decodable {
  let photos: [Results]
}

struct Results: Decodable {
  let url: String?
}
```

On the contrary, if you need a post-processing of data, e.g., converting a `String` to `Date`, you need to implement `init(from decoder: Decoding) throws` yourself. I strongly recommend reading [Encoding and decoding custom types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sample json, there are many free online tools available to create custom swift structs/classes with codable protocol

one such example is https://app.quicktype.io